How to watch Youtube 360 videos in 3840*1080 SBS 3D
I would like to watch the Youtube 360 videos in 3840x1080 SBS (side by side) 3D resolution. In other words, I need one Full HD image for the right eye, and the other Full HD in slightly different angle for the left eye. My virtual glasses can then separate these two views for the different eyes from the wide 3840x1080 video. And I would like preserve the whole 360 degrees perspective, which can be viewed using the head tracking or mouse. The Youtube 360 videos can be watched online in the anaglyph format, why I believe they do contain the necessary stereoscopic information for the task. I can use Windows, but prefer Mac. I could watch the videos using an appropriate online converter, or download the videos and view them with local media players such as VLC. Any suggestions?

You seem to be asking for recommendations for two things, conversion and viewing. This site works best with one question at a time.

Thanks @RohitGupta, I'll try to be more careful next time. On the other hand, there are software doing multiple tasks like this. I hope there could be some single software/service solution, but I might be wrong. At least I haven't find one yet.
